# tense and time and composite sentence

Tags: tense, time

If the eating meal starts at 7:00 AM and finishes at 8:00 AM. the drinking liquor starts at 7:00 AM and finishes at 7:50 AM.

can I say that :

1. I drank the liquor when I ate the meal.
2. I ate the meal when I drank the liquor.

Is I need to use progressive tense ?

Comment: I don't think that just because someone has a fondness for the 7:00 AM to 8:00 AM time period, we should close all of their questions. This seems like it's close to being on-topic, so if you can't find a duplicate I don't think it should have been closed.

Comment: The problem with this type of question is that it is just asking for an interpretation of what a statement means. There are many possibilities, and the *specific* language related issue/problem is not stated. At best this is too broad or unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your sentences would reflect the time sequences you've outlined

> I **drank** liquor **when** I **ate** my meal
>   I **ate** my meal **while** I drank liquor

since there were 50 mins of overlapping time.

You could also say

> I **finished drinking** my liquor **before finishing** my meal.
>   I **had finished** my liquor before I **finished** my meal.

You don't need to use the progressive tense.

Comment: I don't get your meaning. please explain it. thank you.

Comment: Your question asked whether you needed to use **progressive tense**. What are you not understanding?

Comment: what is the "time sequences"? please explain it with examples.

Comment: The **time sequences** are the **time order** you used in your question: liquor 7:00-7:50, eating 7:00-8:00, eating lasts longer that liquor by 10 mins. It might help if I knew you native language

Comment: My native language is Chinese.

Comment: what time sequences do that  "I drank liquor when I ate my meal" reflect ?

Comment: If the eating meal starts at 7:00 AM and finishes at 8:00 AM. the drinking liquor starts at 7:10 AM and finishes at 8:10 AM.can I say that I drank the liquor when I ate the meal ?and why?

Comment: Yes you can say that because the times overlap 7:10-8:00 as long as you **both** ate and drank during that time.